# FOSBundle views not overridden by custom views in Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

There is some weird mismatch between the FosBundle views implementation on my local environment a the DEV one. Both systems share the exact same configuration files and environment variable and are using the same branch. Everything is pulled and pushed on both and the `.gitignore` content is the same.

**Composer.json** (same on both):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "^1.14",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1.0",
    "antimattr/google-bundle": "~2.0@stable",
    "symfony/property-access": "^2.7",
    "leafo/scssphp": "^0.3.2",
    "patchwork/jsqueeze": "~1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*",
    "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4",
    "farmatholin/segment-io-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

**app/config/parameters.yml** (same on both, different db user/pass):

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: dbname
    database_user: root
    database_password: 'pass'
    locale: en
    secret: 'bla'
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true
    google_analytics_name: domain_google_analytics
    google_analytics_account_id: bla
    google_analytics_domain: .domain.com
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_encryption: tls
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: email-smtp.host.com
    mailer_user: user
    mailer_password: blabla
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    set_cli_mailer_host: 'http://domain.com'
    set_use_mailer: swiftmailer
    set_internal_mails_only: false
    segment_write_key:
```

I can also provide the `config.yml` content, but it is the same on both environments. We have overwritten the original FOSBundle views for resetting passwords, signup and others and placed the new templates under our own bundle: `src/UserBundle/Resources/views/Resetting/checkEmail.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    <section>.....</section>
{% endblock %}
```

On the DEV environment it all works as expected, but locally it disregards the overwritten template and just uses the ones in `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Resettin/`

I'm really stuck. Tried those on both:

- composer self-update; composer update; composer install;
- php app/console cache:clear; rm -rf app/cache*
- checked the server for some opcache - none;
- php app/console assetic:dump

No change whatsoever. Everything is the same in code and configurations, yet they load different views. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have updated recently, the `checkEmail.html.twig` template has been renamed to `check_email.html.twig`.

See current template:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Resetting/check_email.html.twig

Comment: forgot to mention that you saved me from going mad. Literally. Thanks again.